# Remove feature based on checkbox

Tags: wix

In install kit I have nearly 18 features. One of them is being hidden and its installation is being controlled by a check box in different screen than feature tree. All works fine until I ran into problem - when user runs the kit in order to remove / add feature, he is not able to remove that feature by check box. How can I achieve that to behave just like in installation?

Comment: In general removing features works by setting the REMOVE attribute to the list of features being removed, but without seeing your WiX or an explanation of how you are trying to remove the feature it's not clear how to answer.

Comment: Thanks. Its hard to post the code since it spread between wxs files / C# Custom Actions